# How to count the amount of times a field appears in a specific 'week' in excel

Tags: excel, database, excel-formula, countif

I have a table:

[image]

I've created a new column called `Distinct Delivery Week`, where I have the weeks 1-52 listed. 
I want to create a count function if  `Week == distinct delivery week`, make it so it does a count and returns the `Channel` category that has the most appearances in each respective week.

For example, if `App - Activation Organic` appears more often than anything else in `Week` 1, then it will be returned in a new column next to `Distinct Delivery Week`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try (as per [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/most-frequent-text-with-criteria) source): `=INDEX(ChannelColumn,MODE(IF(WeekColumn=DistictWeek,MATCH(ChannelColumn,ChannelColumn,0))))`, enter as array formula.

Answer (score 2):

With so many data, it may be helpful if you use a simple PivotTable to count how many times per week does each channel appears, and get TOP 1 per week.

I made a fake dataset kind of like yours:

[image]

Then I created a Pivot Table like this:

1. Fields WEEK and CHANNEL into rows section (first WEEK, second CHANNEL, the order is important)
2. Again, field CHANNEL into VALUES section (make sure the field does a COUNT operation)
3. Applied a VALUE FILTER in column CHANNEL --> **[TOP 10](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/pivottbls/top10_2016.php)**, set it up to show just TOP 1

[image]

It's a really easy way to get a list where you can see the channel that appears most per week.

Comment: A pivot table would indeed be a great way to tackle the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it using [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/most-frequent-text-with-criteria) source. 
The formula I used was:

```
{=INDEX(D1:D74686, MODE(IF(H2:H74686=M2,MATCH(D2:D74686,D2:D74686,0))))}
```

Comment: I don't think that would be correct ;). You'r currently risking returning the wrong result from your index range.

Comment: I don't quite understand sorry, what's the problem with the formula?

Comment: It needs to be: `{=INDEX(D2:D74686,MODE(IF(H2:H74686=M2,MATCH(D2:D74686,D2:D74686,0))))}`. Otherwise the match would return the wrong index to pull :)